# Is thread starvation deadlock happening here in the code?

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock, executorservice

```
//code taken from java concurrency in practice

  package net.jcip.examples;

import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class ThreadDeadlock
       {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public class LoadFileTask implements Callable<String> {
        private final String fileName;

        public LoadFileTask(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public String call() throws Exception {
            // Here's where we would actually read the file
            return "";
        }
    }

    public class RenderPageTask implements Callable<String> 
    {
        public String call() throws Exception
        {
            Future<String> header, footer;
            header = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("header.html"));
            footer = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("footer.html"));
            String page = renderBody();
            // Will deadlock -- task waiting for result of subtask
            return header.get() + page + footer.get();
        }


    }
}
```

This code is take from Java concurrency in practice and as per the authors "ThreadStarvtionDeadlock" is happening here. Please help me finding how ThreadStarvationDeadlock is happening here and where? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more code, we assume some missing parts and we may assume them wrongly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deadlock & Starvation is occurring at following line:

```
return header.get() + page + footer.get();
```

**HOW?**
It will happen if we add some extra code to the program. It might be this one:

```
    public void startThreadDeadlock() throws Exception
    {
        Future <String> wholePage = exec.submit(new RenderPageTask());
        System.out.println("Content of whole page is " + wholePage.get());
    }
    public static void main(String[] st)throws Exception
    {
        ThreadDeadLock tdl = new ThreadDeadLock();
        tdl.startThreadDeadLock();
    }
```

Steps that leading to deadLock:

1. Task is submitted to `exec` for Rendering the page via `Callable` implemented class `RenderPageTask`.
2. `exec` started the `RenderPageTask` in separate `Thread` , the only `Thread` that would execute other tasks submitted to `exec` sequentially .
3. Inside `call()` method of `RenderPageTask` two more tasks are submitted to `exec` . First is `LoadFileTask("header.html")` and second is `LoadFileTask("footer.html")`. But since the the ExecutorService `exec` obtained via code `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` as mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) **uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queueThread** and the thread is already allocated to RenderPageTask , So `LoadFileTask("header.html")` and  `LoadFileTask("footer.html")` will be en queued to the unbounded queue waiting for there turn to be executed by that `Thread`.
4. `RenderPageTask` is returning a String containing the concatenation of output of   `LoadFileTask("header.html")` , body of page and output of `LoadFileTask("footer.html")`. Out of these three parts `page` is obtained successfully by `RenderPageTask` . But other two parts can only be obtained after both tasks are executed by the single Thread allocated by `ExecutorService` . And Thread will be free only after `call()` method of `RenderPageTask` returns . But `call` method of `RenderPageTask` will return only after `LoadFileTask("header.html")` and `LoadFileTask("footer.html")` is returned. So Not letting `LoadFileTask` to execute is leading to **Starvation** . And each task waiting for other task for completion is leading to **DeadLock**

   I hope this makes clear of why thread starvation deadlock is occurring in above code.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was thinking that when the task LoadFileTask("header.html") will be submitted to the executor it will switch on to that (i.e. LoadFileTask(header.html)) task and wil complete then when exec will be submitted the task LoadFileTask(footer.html) then also it will switch on to that task after finishing, it will come to parent task RenderPageTask and will finish. so no deadlock. But i forgot that all tasks will be submitted to a queue and queue has FIFO structure.So the two LoadFileTask tasks will never be executed as the executor has only one thread.Am i correct?

Comment: Yes..Correct..And for the better understanding You should look at this part of `Executors` documentation  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()

Answer (score 2):

The executor I see is a single thread executor and it gets two tasks to do. However these two tasks are not dependent on each other and they order of execution seems not important. Hence the return statement will only pause in [Future.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) calls as much as required to complete one and then another task.

It will be no deadlock in the code you show.

**However** I see one more task in the code (RenderPageTask), it is not clear which executor is actually running its code. If it is the same single thread executor, then deadlock is possible as the two submitted tasks cannot be processed before the main task returns (and this task can only return after the two tasks have been processed).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is not very obvious from the code itself but from the original book where the code is copied from: RenderPageTask submits two **additional** tasks to the Executor to fetch the page header and footer...

If the RenderPageTask were a task independent from the newSingleThreadExecutor, there would be no deadlock at all.